# Delphi, ImageList that handles BOTH png and bitmaps

Tags: delphi, png, bitmap, delphi-7, imagelist

Recently I've found TPngImageList component ( http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26127 ) which is very good, but it handles **only** png images ... I'd like to have some imagelist that allows combining of pngimages with bitmaps, as I'm using lots of bitmaps, and I do not want to spend coming week converting those bitmaps to pngs, yet I want to use be able to add PNG images for coming features ...
So far I used to convert the PNGs to bitmaps using GIMP if I wasn't able to find any replacement.

Comment: If it's going to take you a week to convert them, you're doing it wrong. It should be easily done with a batch operation. You could probably even write a Delphi program to do it for you: `b := TBitmap.Create; b.LoadFromFile; p := TPngImage.Create; p.Assign(b); p.SaveToFile;`

Comment: The problem will be to export the images from each form ... Comparing to replacing the classname of imagelist (two simple regexs + one for adding unit to "uses" list)...

Comment: Why would you need to export anything? Don't you still have the original image files from your art department?

Comment: Lol, there's no art department except me. Actually I do have them but still it takes time to reorder them. Moreover some third party plugins are adding their own bitmaps on runtime, I don't mind changing SDK as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[png2bmp](http://www.google.nl/search?q=png2bmp) and [bmp2png](http://www.google.nl/search?q=bmp2png) come to the rescue for automated commandline conversion of those image files.

As of Delphi 2009, the TImageList supports PNG images natively as [Nick Hodges announced](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2008/08/13/39100).

Comment: thank you, if I don't find anything else I'll need to do it on my own ... D2009 is unreachable for me :(

Comment: The component you are mentioning is meant for D2009/2010. Although the code should be compatible for D7 and up, there are files missing for Delphi versions below D2009. Due to a license change these files are no more available (or better: may not be distributed any longer).

Comment: @michal: please add a tag on which Delphi version (i.e. [delphi-7]) to your post. That makes it easier for participants to tailor their answer to your specifics.

Comment: @Uwe It is indeed a pitty that TPNGImage is not available in Delphi 2007. There are other implementations of PNG support for Delphi and downloads of the old material are still available. Depending on your country of origin, that might be legal or not. http://www.google.nl/search?q=TPNGImage

Comment: I'm glad to keep a copy of the old files in a safe place. The intent for maintaining TPngImageList is simply the fact that I wanted to be compatible with my pre-D2009 code.

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt answer your question, but if you do need to convert them all may I suggest the wonderful [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) over GIMP, it will make your life super easy and convert all your files with one easy script.

Comment: I know ImageMagick however the problem is I need to extract the bitmaps on my own ...

Answer (score 1):

The TImageList component in Delphi 2009 and up handles PNG and BMP files, among many others.

Comment: As of my knowledge and supported through a quick check Delphi 2007 doesn't support PNG files in TImageList. This was introduced in Delphi 2009.

Comment: Now make it available for Delphi 2007 ;-)

Comment: But the transparency is not handled properly. TPngImageList handles transparency properly.